# Very slow network with certain NIC Teaming modes?

Tags: hypervisor

I installed Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard to build a Hyper-V host. 
The server has a built-in network adapter (HP Ethernet 1Gb 2-port 332i Adapter) with the the latest drivers installed and left its DHCP enabled.

1. I created a NIC Team with both network adapters with the following additional properties:
   Teaming mode: Switch independent
   Load balancing mode: Hyper-V Port
   Standby adapter: None
2. I changed the adapter settings of the NIC Team and manually assigned static IP address and DNS server addresses.
3. With Hyper-V Manager i created a new virtual switch (External) connected to "Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver" and "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" enabled.

Now I have 3 Virtual Machines running on the Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter.

The Virtual Machines are running smoothly but only when i use "Hyper-V Port" for Load balancing mode.
With "Address Hash" or "Dynamic" i have extremely slow internet access with every Virtual Machine.

Did i configured this correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to specify the hardware switch being used.

Answer (score 3):

Can you elaborate on "extremely slow internet access?"  Are you having latency problems or slow download speeds or what?

Hyper-V Port Mode essentially assigns a single NIC to a VM.  Even though your team is a 2 gigabit pipe, you'll never have more than 1 gig available to any VM when in this mode.

What switches are these two gigabit ports on the host connected to?  In my experience LACP mode is going to give you the best performance is more situations and it will create less overhead on the host in doing so.  If you're using managed switch(es) LACP is really a cinch to configure, and I can try to help.

Comment: +1 for suggesting LACP, of course if the switch supports it. Everything else is just an elaborate failover, not true bandwidth aggregation.

Comment: The upload and download speed inside the virtual machines have less than 0,5Mbps and of course extremely slow browsing on the internet.
With Hyper-V Port enabled i have normal speeds around 230Mbps down and 19up.
The host is connected to an unmanaged switch.
Maybe i'm better off with disabling the NIC Teaming and configuring one pNIC to manage the host and assign the 2nd pNIC for vEthernet.